# How do i use json data from external file using angularJS restful service

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an application. In that i am retrieving the json data from an

external file using $http.get() method it worked fine. Now i am trying to use angular

restful services. it is working fine in filters, but when i use it in controller it is

displaying undefined.

```
//Service.js File
angular.module('calenderServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Events', function($resource){
return $resource('/EventCalender/:File.json', {}, {
query: {method:'GET', params:{File:'events'}, isArray:true}
});
});


        //This is my app Module
angular.module('calender', ['eventFilters','highlight','event','calenderServices']).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('', {templateUrl: 'template.html',   controller: MonthCtrl}).
  otherwise({redirectTo: '/invalid'});
}]);


     //This is my filter.js
angular.module('eventFilters', ['calenderServices']).filter('compare', function(Events) {
var events=Events.query();
alert(events[0].name); //it is displaying the name "Milestone1" });


     //This is my controller.
function MonthCtrl($scope, Events){
var events=Events.query();
    alert(events[0].name); //it is displaying undefined
    }

     //whenever i try to use the variable 'events' in controller, it is displaying undefined or null.  But in filter it is working fine.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following wont work because **ngResource** makes an ***asynchronous*** http request.

```
var events=Events.query();
alert(events[0].name); // <--- here events is an empty array
```

Usually all you need to do is the following and your data will be available to render in your view

```
$scope.events = Events.query()
```

It looks like a synchronous operation, but it isn't. This is angular's zen at work. You can learn the [details from the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

To further process the data, you could also pass pass a success callback to the `get` method

```
Events.query(function(events){
    // here you have access to the first event's name
    console.log(events[0].name);
});
```

here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NDZ2JWjMUoUvtzEuRUho?p=preview

Comment: I tried this, it was not working. i just changed the name '$scope.events' to '$scope.eve' it is working now. Thanks a lot.